# Post anonymous object via HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post anonymous object via httpclient, however orderId is null and collection empty when it hits controller.

```
    public async Task<Response> CancelOrderAsync(int orderId, ICollection<int> ids)
    {
        Response result = null;
        using (IHttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient())
        {
            var obj = new {OrderId = orderId, Ids = ids};
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            HttpContent postContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync($"{url}/admin/cancel", postContent).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    // Controller
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("cancel")]
    public async Task<Response> Cancel(int orderId, ICollection<int> ids)
    {
        // order is null, collection empty
        ...
```

EDIT:

Changed my controller to this for simplicity

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("cancel")]
    public async Task<SimpleResponse> Cancel(int orderId)
```

Via Postman, i'm posting this body:

```
{
  "orderId": "12345"
}
```

Still, orderId comes in as 0 (zero) ??

Comment: I'm running version 4.6.2

Comment: How is your httpclinet is serializing your data?

Comment: Shouldn't the names match for parameters and fields/properties?

Comment: Can you show code of how you are calling `CancelOrderAsync(int orderId, ICollection<int> ids)`?

Comment: Changing the names to this didn't help: var obj = new {orderId, lineItemIds}; Also, inside CancelOrderAsync the values are there. Orderid and collection are set correctly

Comment: WebApi, value of json is this when debugging: {"orderId":12345,"lineItemIds":[12,343,323,324,3543]}

Comment: According to your code above that JSON is impossible to have created from the Serialise operation, because your C# object contains a property called "Ids" not "lineItemIds". Also your endpoint is expecting "Ids" anyway. See my answer below and see if it helps - you have have the HttpClient handle the serialisation and setting headers etc on your behalf.

Comment: Please see my EDIT

Comment: I guess you need to put both of your parameters to some model class, like `class OrderCancelParameters {public int OrderId {get;set;} public int[] Ids{get;set;}` and then bind like this: `Cancel([FromBody] OrderCancelParameters model)`

Comment: Re your simplified JSON - try `{
  "orderId": 12345
}` - should be an int not a string

Comment: you are passing string instead of int. That is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller action on the server side will need a concrete type to read the entire body of the request

```
public class Order {
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

This is primarily because the action can only read from the body once.

Update action to...

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("cancel")]
public async Task<Response> Cancel([FromBody]Order order) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        int orderId = order.OrderId;
        int[] ids = order.Ids;
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

the original code used to send the request in the example will work as is, but as mentioned it can be improved.

Comment: FromBody still does not work. Please see my simplification. Orderid always comes in as 0 (with or without FromBody) why?

Comment: You do need a class with properties for these types of operations. The only way to pass simple objects that I have found is to do it via params: "?orderid=123".

Answer (score 2):

The HttpClient can do the serialisation for you. See if

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{url}/admin/cancel", obj);
```

works better. Then you don't need to write the serialisation code yourself.

If you still have a problem, use a tool such as Fiddler to monitor the actual request and see what parameter and values are submitted in the request body, to see if they match what's expected by the endpoint.